# Binding Observable collection to wrappanel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an objects of type XYZ , and a viewmodel XYZViewModel. I have a datatemplate for this object

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:XYZViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        / some ui 
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

i have a viewmodel "ListXYZViewModel" which contains list of "XYZViewModel . Now i should display a list of these objects .

Which is the best way to do it ?
I thought of displaying it in a wrappanel.I did this

```
 <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>


<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListXYZViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HomeViewModel}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate }"></ItemsControl>            
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This doesnt work .Any suggestions?

Comment: Is HomeViewModel a collection itself or did you mean to bind ItemsSource to collection on that?

Comment: HomeViewModel is the ObservableCollection  object of XYZViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your `ItemTemplate` explicitly:

```
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding HomeViewModel}" 
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                / some ui 
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HomeViewModel}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListXYZViewModel}">
           <Grid>
              <!-- your ui -->
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```